# where-clause based on current and record date

Tags: sql

I'm struggling to add a where-clause based on the difference of the current date and the date of the record entry. There are some other simplistic clauses as well, but I have no problem with those, so I'm making the demo data simple to highlight the issue I'm having.

Demo dataset:

```
Rec_no  Rec_date    
77  20170606
69  20170605
55  20170601
33  20170520
29  20170501
```

Date is recorded in format yyyymmdd and I'd like to build a where clause to only show records that are created X number of days ago from current date - lets say 10.

So, in this case, only records no 33 and 29 should be shown.

Unfortunately I'm not sure on what the actual DB engine is, but it should be something from IBM.

How could this be done?

Comment: You should not store Dates in this Format. store it as date types

Comment: Can you share the query which you are trying to execute?

Comment: (1) Fix your data structure to store the date using the `date` type.  (2) Tag your question with the database you are using.  If you don't know what engine you are using, then there is little anyone can do (IBM sells DB2, Informix, Netezza, and Vertica.  In addition, almost any other database runs on IBM hardware).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments updating the schema to store the date at the correct type is the best option before you start, however if this is not possible for whatever reason, you would first need to convert the stored date to the correct format at runtime.

I'll write an example in t-sql as that's what I know. Once you have worked out your dbms i can edit to the relevant functions/syntax

```
Select *
FROM Demodataset
WHERE Cast(Rec_Date as datetime) >= dateadd(day,-10,getdate())
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `>=` rather than `=` ?

Comment: @PrabhatG it would be if the question said created less than 10 days ago but the question says records that were created x days ago

Comment: OP says `only records no 33 and 29 should be shown` ,